# Scale image to match paragraph height

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

I am trying to align within a `div` text and `image` besides each other.

Is there a way to scale the image automatically to match the size of the text block, whilst keeping the aspect ratio of the image using no Javascript?

I would like to have the text always on the left, the picture always on the right, and the height of the two blocks being the same.

Illustrated:

#### normal width

[image]

#### widescreen

[image]

#### small screen

[image]

I know that this would of course work only within a range of screen size, and it is ok.

I got so far to be able to scale the image along its height, but then the aspect ratio goes off (sorry for the inline styling):

```html
<div id="frame" style="display: flex; ">
  <div id="text">Text text text...</div>
  <div id="pic"><img src="img.jpg" style="width: 400px; min-height: 100%"/></div>
</div>
```

In between I got another solution, but unfortunately it overflows towards the right - and as an additional benefit, it seems to screw up rendering in Chrome (Firefox and IE seems to handle everything ok)

```css
    .containerdiv {
      display: flex;
      border: green 1px solid;
    }

    .textdiv {
      border: blue 1px solid;
    }

    .imgdiv {
      border: red 1px solid;
      min-height: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
    }

    .imgdiv img {
      height: 100px;
      min-width: auto;
      max-width: auto;
      min-height: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
   <div id="l2_aboutdiv" class="containerdiv">
      <div class="textdiv">
Lorem ipsum molestie netus augue habitant feugiat sollicitudin morbi aenean eget scelerisque bibendum, commodo luctus rutrum conubia proin venenatis senectus blandit porttitor fusce congue.
Hendrerit accumsan eleifend cursus sit in sapien, euismod bibendum pulvinar litora quisque ultrices, a netus orci proin accumsan quisque tempor fusce tempus vestibulum facilisis tellus suspendisse senectus blandit per curabitur mollis elementum.
Cursus proin tortor sodales nisi risus nisl litora, fusce purus augue vehicula hendrerit lacinia magna vivamus, ac imperdiet turpis senectus ultricies vestibulum.
      </div>
      <div class="imgdiv">
        <img src="https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/0a06f9d8-71c6-4d57-b864-6481d273ebcd_1.5993f51524d8f0759355b2c1b657bfb7.jpeg" />
      </div>
   </div>
```

To add, I would prefer a solution where the image is not put in the background of the `div`, as it brings up other implications...

Your suggestions would be very welcome.

Cheers,
Kom

Answer (score 0):

Just set `width:100%;` and `height:auto;` into your picture to scale it, check the code below

```css
#frame{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:row;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

#text{
  border: 5px solid green;
  width:100%;
  margin: 10px;
}

#pic{
  border: 5px solid green;
  width:100%;
  margin: 10px;
}

#pic img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div id="text">Text text text...</div>
  <div id="pic"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400"/></div>
</div>
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jtek934m/)

Comment: OP wants the image to shrink to the height of the content.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, Amine. Just as Andy also mentions, I am rather looking for the image to scale (_that is, shrink or expand, whilst keeping the aspect ratio_) to keep up with the height change of the text block.
Sorry if I was maybe not clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__texts">
        <p>Nunc ultricies sapien tortor. Phasellus dictum orci mauris, id semper mi viverra aliquet. Pellentesque sagittis nisl id justo luctus, vel luctus tortor ornare. Nunc elementum eleifend leo vitae fringilla. Proin interdum consectetur tellus. Suspendisse sapien sapien, tincidunt vitae consectetur vel, imperdiet quis velit. Aliquam venenatis dolor condimentum molestie feugiat. Curabitur turpis enim, placerat in lorem congue, feugiat sollicitudin est. Nullam tincidunt nisl eu posuere porta. Aliquam tempus ligula sem.</p>
        <p>Nunc ultricies sapien tortor. Phasellus dictum orci mauris, id semper mi viverra aliquet. Pellentesque sagittis nisl id justo luctus, vel luctus tortor ornare. Nunc elementum eleifend leo vitae fringilla. Proin interdum consectetur tellus. Suspendisse sapien sapien, tincidunt vitae consectetur vel, imperdiet quis velit. Aliquam venenatis dolor condimentum molestie feugiat. Curabitur turpis enim, placerat in lorem congue, feugiat sollicitudin est. Nullam tincidunt nisl eu posuere porta. Aliquam tempus ligula sem.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container__img">
        <img src="https://static.dezeen.com/uploads/2019/02/best-uk-hotels-interiors-dezeen-roundups-col-4.jpg" class="img"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container{
    width:60%;
    display:flex;
}

.container__texts{
    width:50%;
}

.container__img{
    width:50%;
    position:relative;
}

.container__img img{
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Live exemple here : https://codepen.io/AxelCardinaels/pen/qvZpNy

However, you'll see that on smaller screen, the image will overflow. So, you can either put an overflow:hidden on your image parent top prevent this (but your image will be cut), or, as you mentioned sooner, keep a closer look on specific resolution to prevent this.

Wish you all the best, Axel

Comment: Thanks, Axel, it is indeed one step closer to the desired solution! As I see, your solution is dependent on the fixed 50%-50% split between the two divs. I seriously wonder if there is indeed no solution that would anchor the height of the container__img div to the height of the container__text, and automatically adjust the % split between the text and the image containers...